# Signal R doesnt update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a requirement to show the notification send by administrator.

My menu will be loaded only once.

I also have broadcast notification page where I will send notification to others. On click of save buttom using Hub I am sending the message to the clients.

Here my unread message count (like we have in fb) is placed in the layout .

All my send and receive code is in the Broadcast notification page. Notification count is not getting displayed on the layout menu like (like fb) .

What will be the issue.?

Count is updated on the Webpage where admin will send notification. Other pages say Home page or any other page the notification count which is ther in the layout is not getting updated.

Answer to this will be very helpful for me.

**Hub class** : on button click i am calling this hub method

```
    public void BroadcastNotifications(string message)
    {
        // Save data to database 
        Utility.AddNotification(message);
        // Call method to get the number of unread messages (consider the status = read / unread)
        int UnreadCount = Utility.getUnreadMessageCount();
        UnreadCount = 12;
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BroadcastMessage>();
        context.Clients.All.receiveNotification(message, UnreadCount);

    }
```

**Admin page** where notification message is going to send .

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Notification</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="button" id="button1" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    @section Scripts 
    {
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $.connection.hub.logging = true;
                var proxy = $.connection.broadcastMessage;

                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    $('#button1').click(function () {
                        proxy.server.broadcastNotifications($("#Message").val());
                    });
                });
                proxy.client.receiveNotification = function (message, UnreadCount) {
                    **$("#notification_count").html(UnreadCount);
                    $("#notification_count").show();**
                };
                $.connection.hub.start();
            });
        </script>
    }
```

And the **layout page**  where the notification count should display is

```
    <li class="dropdown" id="notification_li">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-globe fa-inverse dropdown-toggle" 
            data-canvas="body" style="color:gray;padding-top:17px" data-toggle="dropdown" 
            role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span id="**notification_count**" class="notification_count">0</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="popup">
        </ul>
    </li>

This is the _layout page where i have to display the count of unread mesasges.
If i trigger the send button the unread count is getting updated on all the admin add notification open pages. But the other pages it remains empty.
```

**Updated _Layout as per the comment**

I have moved the signal r client call to _layout

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Services</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        var proxy = $.connection.broadcastMessage;

        proxy.client.receiveNotification = function (message, UnreadCount) {
            debugger;
            $("#notification_count").html(UnreadCount);
            $("#notification_count").show();
        };

        $.connection.hub.start();

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#button1').click(function () {
                proxy.server.broadcastNotifications($("#Message").val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
    <body>
    @Html.Partial("_RightMenu")
    **@Html.Partial("_TopMenu")  **//** Notificationcount span is in this partial view**
    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        <div class="row" id="Content">@RenderBody()</div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - FOOTER</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/abcjs")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
  </body>
</html>
```

I have updated as above. In _Layout there are two partial views in which the count i am displaying on one partial view. Is it the correct way to add.

---

tthis is the signal r file generated automatically

```
    $.hubConnection.prototype.createHubProxies = function () {
        var proxies = {};
        this.starting(function () {
            registerHubProxies(proxies, true);
            this._registerSubscribedHubs();
        }).disconnected(function () {
            registerHubProxies(proxies, false);
        });
        proxies.broadcastMessage = this.createHubProxy('broadcastMessage'); 
        proxies.broadcastMessage.client = { };
        proxies.broadcastMessage.server = {
        broadcastNotifications: function (message) {
            return proxies.broadcastMessage.invoke.apply(proxies.broadcastMessage, $.merge(["BroadcastNotifications"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
        }
    };
        return proxies;
    };

    signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
    $.extend(signalR, signalR.hub.createHubProxies());
}(window.jQuery, window));
```

Comment: Thanks for editting..

Comment: Could you show the current code?

Comment: Edited my question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the following: You are only receiving notifications on the admins' sites.

I would place the hub script section within the _layout.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        var proxy = $.connection.broadcastMessage;

        proxy.client.receiveNotification = function (message, UnreadCount) {
            debugger;
            $("#notification_count").html(UnreadCount);
            $("#notification_count").show();
        };

        $.connection.hub.start();

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#button1').click(function () {
                proxy.server.broadcastNotifications($("#Message").val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<li class="dropdown" id="notification_li">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-globe fa-inverse dropdown-toggle"
       data-canvas="body" style="color:gray;padding-top:17px" data-toggle="dropdown"
       role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span id="notification_count" class="notification_count">0</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="popup"></ul>
</li>
```

You can take a look in a sample project I created for the case:

https://github.com/blfuentes/SignalR_StackOverflow_Question

**I updated the nuget packages to the latest version of SignalR 2.2.0**

Comment: I have edited the code as you suggested in the question section . In layout i have two partial views where i will dispaly the count in one partial view. But now also i am missing the notification. I am using vs 2010 , which will not accept signal r 2.2.0 version.

Comment: @jubi the signalR loading should be placed after the jquery. Try like that. You can also open a inspect window in the browser to see the errors you get in the javascript code.

Comment: I have moved the script at the end. After jquery. Just like the code in your reply. But still same behaviour. if i look at the page source jquery is before signal r reference.How can i open inspect window. Are you talking about firebug in firefox.?

Comment: Inspect website is done by Chrome: ctrl+shift+I or right click inspect element, Firefox : right click-> inspect element. Set some `debugger;` where you want to stop while loading.

Comment: Firefox doesnt show this option to inspect element. I may be missing some addons. And i wont be able to install add on as permission restriced here.

Comment: I have placed an alert statement in the signal r client side code on _layout. On page load the alert is coming. but when i click on send button from admin page the alert is not getting . Does it mean the call is not correct. The hub method is executed in hub class on click of send button.

Comment: @jubi the signalR loading should be placed after the jquery. Try like that. You can also open a inspect window in the browser to see the errors you get in the javascript code. –  - I want to mark this as answer. It solves the problem .Thanks blacai.Thanks for answering my first quetion in stackoverflow

Comment: If i add  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script> in header it works. If i add it in <body> of layout page it doesnt work..Also if i add signal r refernece in bundle it doesnot work. Any idea?

Comment: You could show the complete layout, to see the order of the javascript loading. Glad it helped

Comment: Thank you. I wonder whether you can help me with few more queries.While browsing through examples I could find the use of using System.Threading.Tasks;
and overriding Task OnConnected() method. and getting the hub proxy from config file.  Do i need to refer those in my application. My requirement is to send notifications to particular list of users. Do you have any sample to send notifications to only particular users.